# Need help finding Serial connector card for my motherboard (PCI/E to RS422)

Tags: motherboard, pcie

My Motherboard is missing (HP EliteDesk 800 G3 TowerPC ) Serial port.

I have 2 black slots of PCIE empty (named X1PCIEXP1, X1PCIEXP2 on the motherboard) and a yellow PCIE slot empty (named X4PCIEXP).

The two black slots are smaller in size, whereas the yellow slot is longer.

The problem is when I search online for PCIE to serial (Rs422) convertors, the products show small size connector probably I have to connect to the small black colored X1PCIEXP slots.

I am unable to find any serial interface card for X4PCI slot.

Kindly help. So the serial adaptor cards are not available in market for X4PCI slots? or am I missing something? So, should I buy X1PCI slot compatible ones for serial interfacing.

Can I buy this serial interface connector, by advantech?
PCI-1602B-CE

Thank you